# Function that stops when the enter key is the input

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am attempting to write a function for that will be called on later in my program, which is not important right now. The first step is a function that prompts the user for an input until the user hits return. It also only allows for one character at a time to be entered, I have that figured out but not am having trouble because it only will not loop when only one character is provided.
For example, right now if 'hi' is entered it will prompt the user that you may only input one character at a time, but if 'h' was entered it will not ask for anymore and will end the loop.

```
 def get_ch():
     string = ''
     ch = input('Enter a character or press the Return key to finish: ')
     while len(ch) == 1:
         return ch
         string += ch
         ch = input('Enter a character or press the Return key to finish: ')
         if ch == '':
             break
     while len(ch) > 1:
         print("Invalid input, please try again.")
         ch = input('Enter a character or press the Return key to finish: ')

 print(get_ch())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting mixed up with `return`, `break` and `continue` statements. The `return ch` will end the execution of the function, meaning the first `while` can only be executed once.
The below function should constantly loop and build a string until the enter key is pressed with no input.

```
def get_ch():
   string = ''
   while (True):
       ch = input('Enter a character or press the Return key to finish: ')
       if (len(ch) == 1): # single char inputed
           string += ch
           continue
       if (len(ch) == 0): # "enter" pressed with no input
           return string
       # if (len(ch) > 1)
       print('Invalid input, please try again.')
```

Comment: Parenthesis in `if`s and `while`s are redundant

Comment: UGH thank you so much, I guess I need to look over that more.